# What raw data value of S.M.A.R.T. Raw_Read_Error_Rate means?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, synology

My Synology NAS shows the following S.M.A.R.T. data for my Western Digital WD20EADS-00S2B0:
[image]

What is this `Raw data` value equal to `402` means? The current `Value` and `Worst` value looks OK. Should I be worried about hard drive health?

Comment: The **Value** and **Worst** scores go down as the drive deteriorates, so a value of 1 is as bad as it gets. The meaning of the **Raw** column will depend on the particular brand of hard drive.

Comment: @James, thanks, I've added hard drive model to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run a test with WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics and post a screenshot with the results? If you decide to go with an extended test backup your data first because if the software finds any errors, it will try to fix them automatically which can lead to a data loss.

You can download it from here:
http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=mdiuuA

Let me know how it went. :)

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible. Or, is there any way to connect the hard drive to my Macbook Pro? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, Data Lifeguard isn't available for Mac systems. I just wanted to see if the manufacturer's tool will find the same results because those from the screenshot aren't good. Basically, the raw read error attribute value depends on read errors, disk surface condition and indicates the rate of hardware read errors that occurred when reading data from a disk surface. Lower values indicate that there is a problem with either disk surface or read/write heads and it can only grow in number, which is why so my advice here would be to backup the important data you have on the drive.

Comment: Windows download have to moved to https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3&lang=en&i (and for [DOS](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=2)). Other comments are correct, that it is not available for Mac. In fact, it does not seem to have been updated since 2016, and is not longer actively linked to from their software page.